# Metamathematics and the foundations of mathematics

Tags: logic, model-theory, foundations, proof-theory, meta-math

I have some really big doubts about what is the real starting point of all (formal) mathematics.

For example: when I search on internet or study texts about the foundations of mathematics such as model theory, they always name "formulas" and "sets of formulas" quite easily. Model theory is done in set theory, such as ZFC of ZF (*right?*). But if it is really done in set theory (where *everything* is a set), shouldn't this formulas be sets?  From what I know there should be some way to define or code formulas, but I haven't understood it yet so I'm not sure.

This is only one of my doubts, but now I'm going to explain my point of view of mathematics step by step so that it is possible to see if I'm missing something!

First order logic (FOD) can be defined and introduced without using the notion of set. Formal definitions are given in formal languages but since we haven't one yet, we eventually have to define the notions of first order logic in our natural language. This is not a tragedy, because in a certain sense we perfectly know our natural language and if we "assume" it, we  can define the notions of FOD such as terms and well formed formulas. This definitions are not 100% formal, because we stated them in our language, but again, if we "assume" our natural language, then it's fine.

Now we have first order logic and well formed formulas. We can take as a primitive notions the membership predicate $\in$ and the equality predicate $=$. At this point we can state the axioms of set theory (ZFC for example), choose our inference rules and prove theorems about them. We can develop our usual mathematics with this axioms and objects, like analysis or analytic geometry.
At this level, we say things like
$$\exists x \forall y (y \not \in x) \hspace{20pt} \forall x \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists y \in \mathbb{N}(x+y=0) \hspace{20pt}  \lim_{x  \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty \hspace{20pt}  \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}.$$

So far, inside ZFC the notions of "proof", "theory", "inference rule", "axiom", "language" are informal and their definition could be stated only in our informal natural language outside ZFC.

But now if we struggle a bit, we can use sets and what we know about them to formalize into ZFC our intuitive notions of formal languages, predicates, formal systems and formal theories, rules of inference, proofs and theorems (even if I don't know very well how all this complicated definitions are given). So we have defined our FOD idea into ZFC (that makes use of our intuitive FOD!). Now in ZFC we are able to formally define what a formal theory is and study it, defining the relations of "provable" $\vdash$ for set of predicates and "satisfiable" $\vDash$ between algebraic structures ("models") and set of predicates. At *this* level we can now say things like 
$$\lbrace p,q\rbrace \vdash p \wedge q \hspace{20pt} \mathcal{M} \vDash \sf PA \hspace{20pt} \textrm{Con}(T) \Leftrightarrow \nexists \varphi ( T \vdash \varphi \wedge T \vdash \neg \varphi)$$
and *all* of this objects are sets of our intuitive ZFC domain of discourse, so we can treat them as usual sets. In short, we are doing *metamathematics* in ZFC, studying theories (such as PA) written in some formal languages and asking if they are consistent, complete or sound, and all this objects are just *sets*. We could also study ZFC itself and define it as the set of axioms that we initially stated before. Note that now we have a formal definition of what a proof is for the formal languages that we have defined, but this is a definition for our *object theories* and not for our first ZFC, which has been defined just with our natural language (unless we are studying ZFC itself).

Is this view of mathematics correct or is there something that I'm missing?

I see that often it is used a completely different approach, and sometimes I even find that some metamathematical argouments or definitions are circular. I feel there's something that I'm not getting... but I don't know what it is.

Thank you for the possible help :P

Comment: Regarding your first question, sure, when we formalize model theory in set theory, our formulas, like any other mathematical objects, will be encoded as sets. If you are familiar with Godel numbering, it is the same as that, only with sets rather than numbers. And in set theory we can encode formulas much more naturally off the shelf, e.g. using nested ordered pairs to represent the syntax tree.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand the rest (but I haven’t read that closely), but note that while model theory requires some set theory in the metatheory to formalize, we don’t need model theory to carry out and verify proofs in ZFC. For this a very weak, even finitary metatheory suffices.

Comment: So in model theory when we are reasoning with a set of formulas we are actually considering their Godel number / Godel set? But then, even if it's like that, how can we be sure that our theorems apply to formulas of other theories if they are just sets/numbers?

Comment: Yes, you can "code" syntax into very "poor" set theory : [Hereditarily finite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set). See e.g. M.Fitting, [Incompleteness in the land of sets](https://books.google.it/books?id=8tmIGAAACAAJ).

Comment: @Luis Well, when we formalize it in set theory, yes that’s what we’re considering. Just like when we formalize analysis in set theory, our real numbers are Dedekind cuts of rationals, which are equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers, which are ordered pairs of naturals, which are finite ordinals, and our functions are sets of ordered pairs, etc. I don’t understand your question. What “theorems” and what “other theories.”

Comment: @Luis and btw I should have emphasized  above that the reason we need nontrivial amounts of set theory to do model theory has nothing to do with formulas which we know can be encoded in much weaker theories. It is to handle structures.

Comment: For example, if I consider the theory T composed by **∃x(x=x)** and **∀y(y=y)**, (which are just strings of symbols in first order logic defined using our natural language) with basic inference rules, how proving its consistency using model theory and string coded as numbers ensures that the theory is consistent if in the theory T those axioms are just primitive strings defined in our language and not sets?

Comment: @Luis Well, If we’re formalizing our metatheory in set theory, we’re doing everything in set theory, both on the proof theory and model theory side. We can establish the relevant soundness result as a formal theorem of ZFC. This tells you within our formalized metatheory that semantic consistency implies syntactic consistency (i.e. the nonexistence of a proof of contradiction).

Comment: I think you should decide and explain what it is that you want to do with mathematics. Your question does not give any information about your important decision.

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that many texts in mathematical logic are *not* attempting to be foundational. They assume you're already fine with ZFC somehow, and are simply trying to explore logic from a mathematical perspective. If you took them as foundational, i.e. as trying to *justify* logic, then they really would be circular. Texts with a more foundational orientation usually work in PA or PRA, and the formulas will usually be represented by numbers, not sets. These usually take a proof-theoretic rather than model-theoretic approach.

Comment: Regarding first order logic (terms, well formed formulas, logical connectives...), is it defined just using our natural language as I said in the question?

Comment: @LuisOrion It can be, or it can be formalized within some other system. For example, if I want to study first-order logic in Coq, then I will define terms and well-formed formulas in Coq, not natural language. There isn't just one way to do things.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Can you give me an example of this "syntax tree encoding" that you mentioned in your first comment with some arbitrary formula please?

Comment: @Luis I know this is in various books but no reference springs to mind. You use the parsability of ordered tuples. For terms you can encode the n-th variable as $(n,0)$ and you can encode a set parameter $a$ as $(a,1).$ For formulas, you can write atomic formulas $t=u$ as $(0,c(t),c(u))$ where $c$ is the coding function we’re defining recursively. Similarly for $t\in u$ only with a $1.$ Then can code $\lnot \phi$ as $(2, c(\phi)),$ similarly for $\land$. $\exists x_n\phi$ would be $(4,n,c(\phi)).$ So $\exists x_1 (x_1\in x_2)$ would be encoded $(4, 1, (1, (1,0),(2,0))).$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wow, thanks! If you or anyone else could say me the title of some books/ texts where this is *precisely* and *formally* explained (regarding not only this special encoding but even how a "first order language" is defined and other informations and theorems about it in the classic model/proof theoretic way), I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @LuisOrion A book that might be of interest is Melvin Fitting's Incompleteness in the land of sets. Haven't really studied it much myself, but looking through it, it seems to have a pretty detailed treatment of encoding syntax with finite sets. It is (as its title suggests) mainly focused on arithmetic and the incompleteness phenomenon, not model theory, but it looks like it has a small amount of semantics in there too.